# How can I listening hiding the Picture in Picture mode in a Swift iOS app by swiping left or right?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, picture-in-picture

In my iOS app developed with Swift, two users can engage in a mutual video call.
After a user switches the call to Picture in Picture mode, I want to detect if they swipe right or left to minimize the Picture in Picture view and, accordingly, close the camera.

How can I listen for these swipe gestures and handle them appropriately?

[image: pip mode active and hided]

I've tried the Picture in Picture delegates, but I couldn't achieve the desired result.

Comment: Best would be to see a minimum reproducible example. At least, is it UIKit or SwiftUI? Swipe gesture is pretty standard, what problem are you facing?

Comment: @soundflix I'm using UIKit. I want to listen for when the Picture in Picture is hidden or not, and make changes accordingly. You can see the screenshot on the right.